# Need some help with Joins

Tags: t-sql, join

So I have a proc that is selecting records from a database. The proc has a `varchar` parameter containing an IP Address.

The proc is selecting records from a table that has a `messageId` column (the primary key).

I have ANOTHER table that links IP's with Messages. This table has a column with an `ip` and a column with a `messageId`.

When selecting records from the first table, I want to also select all columns from the second table where the IP address passed into the proc matches the IP address in the second table for the `messageId` on each of the records I am bringing back.

Thanks guys.

Comment: I have an entire proc written up but I don't ever get joins right, so I left this part out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a left join like so:

```
 select *
 from table1  -- table with messageid
 left join table2   -- table with ip
    on table1.messageid = table2.messageid
  where table2.ip = @ip
```

Comment: How would I also select the columns from the second table though?

Comment: Nevermind figured that out. So what will happen if there is no record in the second table for the message/ip? What will it return for those columns?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your set up looking something similar to this:

```
*Table1*

MessageId | ColA | ColB

*Table2*

MessageId | Ip | ColX | ColY
```

Your sql would be something like this:

```
 Select t1.MessageId, t1.ColA, t1.ColB, t2.Ip, t2.ColX, t2.Coly
 From Table2 t2
 Lef Outer Join Table1 t1 on t1.MessageId=t2.MessageId
 Where t2.Ip = @varcharIP
```

Comment: Well I want all the records I am selecting from table 1 no matter what, and only the extra columns from the second table if there are records, but if there aren't, I still want the columns from the first table.

Comment: Sounds like a `LEFT JOIN` to me

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
SELECT m.*, i.ip FROM Messages m
LEFT OUTER JOIN IPs i ON m.messageID = i.messageID
WHERE m.messageID = 'YOURMESSAGEID'
```

Switching out Messages and IPs for your respective tables